# git: fetching another branch fails

Tags: git, git-fetch

I am doing parallel development with my team mate. We both created feature branches off of master (branchA - mine and branchB - his).
I want to rebase on top of his branch. I am in my local branch (branchA) and issue the following command:

> git fetch branchB

I get the following error:

> fatal: 'branchB' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

However, branchB does exist. How can I fix it?

Comment: One does not fetch branches in git but remotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the name of his remote. `git fetch remote_name branchB`